# Send a reference to a parent object from a context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, contextmenu

I am using C# and WPF and I have no idea how to accomplish the following:

I have a TreeView, which contains TreeViewItems. In every TreeViewItem.Header, there is a Stack Panel which contains an icon, a text and a ContextMenu (the cotext menu is defined in TreeView.Resources . When the user right-clicks on the stack panel, the context menu is shown, which contains a MenuItem. On Click event of that MenuItem, a custom dialog is created, and this dialog needs a reference to the TreeViewItem that opened that context menu. How can I get that reference?

Here is the XAML code where the tree view is defined:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Margin="5, 3, 5, 3">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="RoomsContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Add Rooms" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="addRom_Click">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/GroupAddressCreatorWPF;component/Images/add.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeView.Resources>

    <TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource RoomsContextMenu}">
                <Image Width="5" Height="5" Margin="3,0" 
                       Source="/GroupAddressCreatorWPF;component/Images/red.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Main area 1" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem.Header>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

This is the click event implementation from the menu item which created the custom dialog, and where I need access to the TreeViewItem:

```
private void addRom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddRoomsDialog roomsDialog = new AddRoomsDialog(???);
    roomsDialog.Show();
}
```

Comment: What is currently contained in the sender parameter when addRom_Click is called?

Comment: I guess a reference to the object that sends the click event, in this case MenuItem

Answer (score 1):

Thanks lenkan.
I had to modify my XAML file so the user is able to delete childs in tree view. Now my XAML file looks like this:

```
               <TreeView.Resources>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="RoomsContextMenu">
                        <MenuItem Header="Add Rooms" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="addRom_Click">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/GroupAddressCreatorWPF;component/Images/add.png" />
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainArea}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RoomCollection}">
                        <Border Width="150" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Margin="2" Padding="2" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource RoomsContextMenu}">
                                <Image Width="10" Height="10" Margin="3,0" 
                                   Source="/GroupAddressCreatorWPF;component/Images/blue.png" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainAreaName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Room}">
                        <Border Width="132" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="10" Height="10" Margin="3,0" 
                                   Source="/GroupAddressCreatorWPF;component/Images/green.png" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RoomName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
```

The problem now comes in this piece of code:

```
roomsTreeView.ContextMenuOpening += (senderContextMenu, eContextMenu) =>
{
    mMainAreaItem = ((TreeView)senderContextMenu).Items.OfType<TreeViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.IsMouseOver);
};
```

Since the items in the tree view are not TreeViewItem (they are MainArea), mMainAreaItem in the above code is always -1. I have also tried to do the following:

```
roomsTreeView.ContextMenuOpening += (senderContextMenu, eContextMenu) =>
{
    mMainAreaItem = ((TreeView)senderContextMenu).Items.OfType<MainArea>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.IsMouseOver);
};
```

But that doesn´t compile since MainArea doesn't contain IsMouseOver property. Is here a easy way to fix this? (Sorry, but I am quite new to C# and WPF).

Comment: So, what is the actual item that you need? Is it the image or the text?

Comment: I need the MainArea object, so I can add a room on its RoomCollection.

Comment: Ok. The easiest way to do achieve this is to put the context menu inside the Border element. That way, you can access the mainarea from ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext.

Comment: That didn´t work. ((FrameworkElement)sender) is of type FrameworkElement{Controls.TreeView}; and ((FrameworkElement)sender.DataContext is a null object.
However, I did a work around. casting the sender as a TreeView and getting the SelectedItem property (which is a MainArea object). The problem here was that when the user right clicked on an item, the item was not selected, so I changed that to select the item that creates the context menu just before opening the context menu and getting the MainArea from the SelectedItem property.

Answer (score 0):

Add a *Name* to your TreeView so that you get access to it via an instance field.

```
<TreeView Margin="5, 3, 5, 3" x:Name="TreeView">
```

Then, in your control or window constructor, listen for the ContextMenuOpening and ContextMenuClosing events to store the currently active item in the tree view in an instance field. You will then have access to it in your click event handler.

```
private TreeViewItem activeItem;

public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // sender is the TreeView itself. Just iterate through the items
    // and retrieve the first one where IsMouseOver returns true.
    TreeView.ContextMenuOpening += (sender, e) =>
    {
        activeItem = ((TreeView) sender).Items.OfType<TreeViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.IsMouseOver);
    };

    TreeView.ContextMenuClosing += (o, e) =>
    {
        activeItem = null;
    };
}

private void addRom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    // Once we get here, activeItem will reference the TreeViewItem
    // that was under the cursor when the context menu was opened.
    AddRoomsDialog roomsDialog = new AddRoomsDialog(activeItem);
    roomsDialog.Show();
}
```

Alternatively, the RoutedEventArgs *e* variable in the *ContextMenuOpening* event handler will hold a reference to the item that was clicked. I.e., the TextBlock or the Image. You can store a reference to that object instead if that is applicable to your problem.